# Getting a list of all job status through Spark Rest API

Tags: apache-spark

I recently migrated Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.0 . 
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications would give me the list of all jobs in JSON in the older version.
For 2.1 I had to setup a history server to get the same result with port 18080.
Is there a configuration I'm missing, which would allow me to get all jobs without setting up a history server?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? Even i got the same issue by updating spark to 2.0

Comment: I am able to get a list of jobs that are queued or running after setting up a history server.